# What AI tools could I use to modify educational sign language videos?

Tags: video, artificial-intelligence, video-editing

I have been tasked with researching the current tools in these matters, and its for educational sign language videos. The problem with these videos is that the person signing usually does not want to appear in the videos, so it would be great if it would be possible to film the video and modify it afterwards in a way that the person is no longer recognisable, through their face or body. The problem I have been facing is AI messing up the hands in the videos so that the sign language cannot be understood. I have tried several AI tools, but none of them have produced desirable results. I have already tried: Kaiber ai, Vidnoz ai, runway